# How to prevent Amazon SageMaker from splitting my .txt file into lines?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, text-classification, amazon-ground-truth

I want to create a labeling job for workers to label my text data. Each text file should be labeled as an entity. SageMaker seems to split my text into lines, so each line can be labeled, which does not make any sense for my project. I used GroundTruth option ‘Create a labeling job’ and could not find any configuration options to prevent the splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly replace all the new line characters in your text i.e "/n" with a `<br/>` tag. Then you will  need to create a custom labelling job , also you can choose from the pre-defined templates for the initial code. Inside the  tag just include "skip_autoescape" it will help in considering the `<br/>` as the line break and you can see the desired output as a single entity.

Follow below docs for more references :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-custom-templates-step2.html